# strip timestamp/syntax-sequence from python string

Tags: python, string, timestamp, strip

I'm working on a python script which retrieves values from an sdict as a string value. Many of the returned values contain a timestamp depending on the sdict, which is a tad annoying.

Eg. `<2006-12-20 00:10:24 Cattle is a tree>`

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to remove the `2006-12-20 00:10:24` from the returned value. Has anyone got any ideas? I was thinking I could strip anything between - characters. However, the returned values often contain - throughout.

Comment: Could you be more precise about the values you're working with? Are they all strings consisting of a "<", then a timestamp in that format, then a space, then some other stuff, then a ">"? Or is there more variation than that? For that matter, are you certain that the values you're retrieving really are strings? (It's not uncommon for non-string objects to be displayed in ways that look like what you've shown here.)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Try using regular expressions to match the pattern of the dates.

Comment: Look at re.sub  ( http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub )  If you don't know re, no better time to learn!

Comment: Thanks heaps guys! That was the returned output of the irilipicant function. I got it working using the syntax suggested below "re.sub(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ', '', value)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good candidate for using regular expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<2006-12-20 00:10:24 Cattle is a tree>'
>>> re.sub(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ', '', s)
'<Cattle is a tree>'
```